# How to make a pop up alert while selecting a particular cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to code in VBA for making a pop-up alert while selecting a particular cell, this is like a missing out of a mandatory field, it needs to display an alert for missed out cell while going on next cell

```
Sub macro1(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("F3").Value = "NWOO" Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E4:F4")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You have missed a cell " & Target.Address & vbCrLf & "Please input a number", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
' Macro1 Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+z
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, the code is good. However, you need to code in a SelectionChange event, which will be triggered when a sheet's range selection changes.

Place sub below in your sheet's module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("F3").Value = "NWOO" Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E4:F4")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You have missed a cell " & Target.Address & vbCrLf & "Please input a number", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
    End If
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+z
End If

End Sub
```

For the keyboard shortcut you will probably be better off using [Application.Undo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.undo) than using [SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys). SendKeys can be very unreliable.

Comment: Tim edit the event, you said the one needed but wrote another.